# How to import function from file without executing the rest of the code in the imported file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I would like to import only the piece of code that I explicitly mention to import without either importing the libraries imported in the imported file or executing any other code in the imported file.

In other words, only the function(s) to be imported should be imported

Example : `foo.py` (file from which to import the function) -

```
import numpy as np

print('imported foo')
print(np.array([1]))

def func():
    print('a')
    print(np.array([2]))
```

`bar.py` (file which imports) -

```
from foo import func

func()
```

but the output is

```
imported foo
[1]
a
[2]
```

I'll be happy if the output is `a` and then some error of `np` not defined.

**EDIT** - This may differ from the duplicate as I also don't want to import the libraries.

Comment: The moment you import a module it will execute anything that is executable in the global space. You are executing the `print` function in the global space, so there is no avoiding that unless you put those prints within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition

Comment: See also [Why is Python running my module when I import it, and how do I stop it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6523791)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the tip. Now, I only get `a` and `[2]` but I'd also want it to raise an error of it not being able to detect `np`. Anything apart from the `__all__` workaround?